# Passing and testing symbol in a function

Tags: functions, symbols

Would like to pass a symbol to a function that tests for the symbol before executing certain tools.

Let there be a function named `(highlight-mode-line)` such that when it is called with `(highlight-mode-line` reverse)` it will highlight with the colours reversed.

Comment: Question is unclear: what do you mean by "test for the symbol"?

Comment: Do `(galex-markup 'extent)`.  Then test for `'extent` in the function to do something.

Comment: "test for 'extent in the function to do something" is just as unclear as "test for the symbol". The question is vacuous, so far.

Comment: Ok.  Let there be a function named `(highlight-mode-line)`, but if I do `(highlight-mode-line \`reverse)`, it will highlight with the colours reversed.

Comment: *Add the info to your question*: *you* should not reply with a comment to comments asking for clarification. You should clarify the question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to [define functions](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Defining-Functions) and [use conditionals](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Conditionals) is very basic knowledge for any language.  I urge you to **[RTFM](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/R/RTFM.html)**, but I'll also give you an answer.

```lisp
(defun highlight-mode-line (&optional style)
  (cond ((equal style 'reverse) (message "reverse"))
        (t (message "default"))))
```

You can use [`equal`](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Equality-Predicates#function-equal-object1-object2) to compare symbol equality.

Comment: I have some problem understanding conditionals. For instance, with optional `style` does the command skip the following part `(unless (equal style 'reverse)` when `style` is not used? In some languages I have to test whether the argument exists first before testing value for it.

Comment: @konmi  Why on earth don't you try it? Instead you ask a question (in a comment to an answer, which is a no-no in any case) that takes longer to type and are willing to wait for an answer that may never come. By trying it, you can understand things better *and* you can have an answer in seconds.

Comment: Yes, I am trying and doing various tests.

Comment: I do not understand something.  When I do `emacs -Q` I get a light theme.  But when I call my start function `(mypackage 'nogo)`, I get a dark background even when no customisations have been executed.

Comment: THIS IS NOT A DISCUSSION SITE!!!! If you have a new question, do not ask it in a comment - ask a new question.